# Is it possible to make Scalate templates that are like Apache Wicket templates?

Tags: templates, scala, wicket, scalate

Is it possible to make Scalate templates that are like Apache Wicket templates? If so, how? Are there any projects out there already doing this? If so, which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://bowlerframework.org/
Sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: Bowler adds Squery support in its latest codes, though not stable, but usable.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Scala + Wicket. This is nice combination.

Comment: This is just an experiment. For serious projects I chose the combination Scala + Wicket. I agree with you, completely. :)